# Input text robotframework appium doesn't work

Tags: input, text, appium, robotframework

I'm developing automated tests on an android application using Appium and Robotframework. Last three days I have the error below. I tried it with lots of locators and it doesn't work. FWIW, I can click on the element.

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    30    1    AppiumLibrary.Input Text    //android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='montantMobile']    ${amount}
```

---

```
Keyword 'AppiumLibrary.Input Text' failed after retrying for 30 seconds.
The last error was: InvalidElementStateException: 
Message: ACTION_SET_PROGRESS has failed on the element 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@56311; 
boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 324, 56); boundsInScreen: Rect(23, 405 - 874, 552); 
packageName: com.xxxxx.android.application; 
className: android.widget.EditText; 
text: Montant du virement; 
error: Saisie incorrecte; 
maxTextLength: -1; 
contentDescription: null; 
tooltipText: null; 
viewIdResName: montantMobile; 
checkable: false; 
checked: false; 
focusable: true; 
focused: true; 
selected: false; 
clickable: true; 
longClickable: false; 
contextClickable: false; 
enabled: true; 
password: false; 
scrollable: false; 
importantForAccessibility: false; 
visible: true; 
actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_HTML_ELEMENT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CONTEXT_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_LONG_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_TEXT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PASTE - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_UNKNOWN - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_PROGRESS - null]'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Appium cannot input text because field has `maxTextLength: -1;`, but you can click on the element beacause it has `clickable: true;`. Are you sure it works manually and you have correct locator?

Comment: Hello Viliam, thank you for your Answer. I think that my Xpath is correct because it works by clicking on it. I resolved it by using this Keyword : Press Key     $KeyNumber